# Mule ESB Community version Message mapping techniques

Tags: xslt, mapping, mule, transformation, dozer

We are currently using Mule ESB Community version and looking for techniques to transform messages from one format to another. We  have tried  XSLT for XML mapping. Java object mapping and Dozer mappings so far.We deal with XML, FLAT,Json messages.Would like to know if there are more options which are visually easy to map and maintain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirement ... For **XML** mapping **XSLT** is a good choice,in some cases you can also map elements of **XML** using **XPATH**

For **JSON** you first need to parse the payload with **JSON** to Object transformer and then you can map with each **JSON** element

But if you want any other option than these transformer, then I will suggest **Datamapper**, which can map and transform almost all type of payload starting from **XML**, **JSON**, **POJO**, **flat** files and it is also **graphically supported** as you mentioned in your requirement...

but again it is not available in **Community** **edition** and only feature of **Enterprise** **edition**:-

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Datamapper+User+Guide+and+Reference